# Using Texcount but how do I ignore macro contents?

Tags: texcount

I am using TexCount to do word counts on my document. I am using a `\cmt` command to write inline comments so anything in `\cmt{}` does not get printed.

I am using the texcount command `%TC: macro \cmd [1]` to try and ignore these comments

```
%TC: macro \cmd [1]

\documentclass[]{article}
\immediate\write18{texcount.pl -total \jobname.tex -out=\jobname.sum}

\newcommand{\cmt}[1]{}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\newcommand\wordcount{\verbatiminput{\jobname.sum}}

\begin{document}


One
\wordcount
\cmt{Two Three Four Five}

\end{document}
```

I should be getting Words in Text: 1 but it's coming out as 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is `%TC:macro \cmt [state1]` if there is only one argument.

The state1 can have a specific value, if the argument should be ignored, use `%TC:macro \cmt [ignore]`

```
\documentclass[]{article}

%TC:macro \cmt [ignore]

\immediate\write18{texcount -total \jobname.tex -out=\jobname.sum}


\usepackage{verbatim}
\newcommand\wordcount{\verbatiminput{\jobname.sum}}

\newcommand{\cmt}[1]{}

\begin{document}


One
\wordcount
\cmt{Two Three Four Five}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. That's solved it. Tnks